# How do I serialize IHtmlString to JSON with Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a field containing raw HTML published via JSON that was recently converted from a string to an IHtmlString. When that change happened, the field went from being a JSON string to being an empty object and a bunch of things consuming that JSON started blowing up.

```
// When it was a string...
{
    someField: "some <span>html</span> string"
}

// When it became an IHtmlString...
{
    someField: { }
}
```

Ignoring any arguments against raw HTML in JSON since it is moot for this project, how do I get the expected string in my JSON serialization?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Background

Both Json.NET and the default .NET JavaScriptSerializer will treat instances of `IHtmlString` as an object with no properties and serialize it into an empty object. Why? Because it is an interface with only one method and methods don't serialize to JSON.

```
public interface IHtmlString {
    string ToHtmlString();
}
```

#### Solution

For Json.NET, you will need to create a custom `JsonConverter` that will consume an `IHtmlString` and output the raw string.

```
public class IHtmlStringConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return typeof(IHtmlString).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) {
        IHtmlString source = value as IHtmlString;
        if (source == null) {
            return;
        }

        writer.WriteValue(source.ToString());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) {
        // warning, not thoroughly tested
        var html = reader.Value as string;
        return html == null ? null : System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString.Create(html);
    }
}
```

With that in place, send an instance of your new `IHtmlStringConverter` to Json.NET's `SerializeObject` call.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectWithAnIHtmlString, new[] { new IHtmlStringConverter() });
```

#### Sample Code

For an example MVC project where a controller demos this, head over to [this question's GitHub repository](https://github.com/patridge/JsonNetIHtmlStringTesting).

Comment: When I try to use this I get a `Unable to cast object of type 'MyNameSpace.HtmlStringJsonConverter' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter'` error, any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is not taking the type into consideration by changing ReadJson into the code below should fix that. reference: https://sebnilsson.com/blog/serialize-htmlstring-mvchtmlstring-in-json-net/

```
var value = reader.Value as string;

// Specifically MvcHtmlString
if (objectType == typeof(MvcHtmlString))
{
    return new MvcHtmlString(value);
}

// Generally HtmlString
if (objectType == typeof(HtmlString))
{
    return new HtmlString(value);
}

if (objectType.IsInterface && objectType == typeof(IHtmlString))
{
    return new HtmlString(value);
}

// Fallback for other (future?) implementations of IHtmlString
return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, value);
```

**Update:** Adding a interface check to IHtmlString.