# how to serialize a long string and maintain the formatting?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, http-post

I have a console application and writing a string content (a long comment you can say) through POST method to LiquidPlanner comment. I have a long string having some html tags and maintains a format like following.

[image: Real time data during debugging from text visualizer, you can see formatted comment i am getting.]

When i am serializing through JsonConvert.SerializeObject then formatting of that comment is breaking and writing on other side as messy text as following.

[image: Here you can see after serialization its going messy, no formatting is maintained.]

i tried following link but was not helpful.
[Link for serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350392/how-do-i-serialize-ihtmlstring-to-json-with-json-net)

how can serialize exact same ? is there any way please let me know asap, thank you in advance.

Comment: URL encode or base-64 encode your string before sending it?

Comment: No, actually according to api Username and password must be base-64 encoded before sending the request, so in my POST function i have username:password in base64 encoded only, not the comment string.

Comment: Where do you get the data from? What are the line terminating chars? `\r\n`, `\n` or `\r`?

Comment: Have you checked the output of the call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inputString)`? There shouldn't be an issue. I think it's rather displaying on LiquidPlanner side (don't know this tool). May be for LiquidPlanner you should make some replacements of the newlines.

Comment: During debugging i seen serialized data having \r\n, \n., I tried manually posting comments on LiquidPlanner, that time formatting is not breaking. Its mean liquidPlanner support the formatting. But from my tool where i am serializing object, is breaking formatting in POST function.

Comment: I tried DataContractJsonSerializer it also not helpful it showing data in more messy way.

Comment: @GrawCube are you there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause of Error:**
I solved the issue, actually what happening in original string you can see the new line so when this string pass into the string variable then .Net environment put \r\n on every new line and when i serialize from the newton.json library it put one more slash in \r and \n (\\r\\n) so when i POST the string in LiquidPlanner, LiquidPlanner fail to interpretate (\\r\\n) and write as text non formatted way.

**Solution of Error:**
what i did, i used regex and replaced the \\r\\n with 
 tag from the serialized string and posted, and it worked for me.

```
string.Join("<br/>", System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(createCommentJson, @"(?:\\r\\n|\\n|\\r)"));
```

and it posted in formatted way.
:)